# Custom Rescoring in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ranking, levenshtein-distance

I simply want to score the results of my "more_like_this_field" query on my own.
Why doesn't this work?

```
{ 
      "query": { 
            "function_score": { 
                    "more_like_this_field": { 
                            "test_field": { 
                                    "like_text": "this is a test", 
                                    "min_term_freq" : "0", 
                                    "min_doc_freq": "0" 
                            } 
                    }, 
                    "functions": [ 
                            { 
                                    "script_score": { 
                                            "script": "_score * 2" // just an example
                                    } 
                            } 
                    ] 
             } 
      } 
}
```

Furthermore I like to calculate the score with levenshtein distance. I know there is a fuzzy search with levenshtein, but it's limited and also to slow.
I only want to score the top n results with it.
Is that somehow possible?